# Why does ServiceStack's AppHostBase.Configure take a Container parameter?

Tags: servicestack

`AppHostBase` already contains a `Container` property (which resolves to `EndpointHost.Config.ServiceManager.Container` if defined), so why not just use `Instance.Container` (e.g., for registering dependencies, plugins, etc.) inside `Configure` or elsewhere inside any `AppHost` implementations?

I do note that `Configure` is a public call, so it could technically be called from anywhere, although it appears that `AppHostBase.Init()` is the only place in the ServiceStack codebase that does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configuration and registration should happen within the context of the `AppHost.Configure(Container)` method, after which point it should remain immutable (readonly) for ThreadSafety.

The Container is passed in because that's where all the application dependencies should be registered on. The Container property itself should therefore be treated as **read only** which is why core classes like `IAppHost` only exposes a [IResolver.TryResolve](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IResolver.cs) method.

Comment: Right, but why not do `Configure() { Instance.Container.Register<...>(...); }` instead of `Configure(Container container) { container.Register<...>(...); }`? They appear to have the same end result -- though I haven't traced it through fully -- and it would be a simpler design.

Comment: The API leads you to what to do. Accessing the singleton does not convey that it should only be used within that scope, it makes it look like you can access and mutate it at anytime - which is not the case.

Comment: That makes sense; you're exposing the singleton for reading in other circumstances but don't want its `Container` changed. And I see that `Configure(Container)` is defined in `IFunqlet`, which is why that method is public and not protected (since otherwise it seems that `AppHostBase.Init()` is the only thing that needs to call it).